# Creating HTML list from Javascript object array

Tags: javascript, html, list

Below i have a catalog of products I am trying to generate as (< li>) in HTML. Currently I have the (const catalog) and a searchbox, I have been able to take the input of the searchbox and push it into an array. My problem at the moment is I am not sure how to then use the input of the searchbox in a function to get the product from the array. Currently, I have hardcoded a search term to look through the array but I need to make this equal to the input of the searchbox. After this I want to generate an HTML (< li>) which will display the products from the catalog that match the search term.

Any help would be greatly appreciated Thanks.

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return getquery()">
  <p>Please insert the items</p>
  <input type="text" id="box" />
</form>
```

JS

```
const catalog = {
  Ipad: {
    name: "Ipad",
    key: "ipad",
    keywords: ["tablet", "apple"],
    price: 800,
  },
  Iphone: {
    name: "Iphone",
    key: "iphone",
    keywords: ["apple", "phone"],
    price: 1200,
  },
  GalaxyTablet: {
    name: "GalaxyTablet",
    key: "galaxytablet",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    price: 800,
  },
  GalaxyPhone: {
    name: "GalaxyPhone",
    key: "galaxyphone",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    price: 1000,
  },
  HTCPhone: {
    name: "HTCPhone",
    key: "htcphone",
    keywords: ["htc", "phone"],
    price: 650,
  },
  SonyPhone: {
    name: "SonyPhone",
    key: "sonyphone",
    keywords: ["sony", "phone"],
    price: 850,
  },
  WindowsPhone: {
    name: "WindowsPhone",
    key: "windowsphone",
    keywords: ["phone", "windows"],
    price: 800,
  },
};

const query = [];
const finalResult = [];

function getquery() {
  boxvalue = document.getElementById("box").value;
  query.push(boxvalue);
  console.log(boxvalue);
  console.log(query);
  return false;
}

const searchKeyword = "apple";

for (const items in catalog) {
  const obj = catalog[items];
  if (obj.keywords.indexOf(searchKeyword) != -1) {
    finalResult.push(obj);
  }
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution

```js
const catalog = {
  Ipad: {
    name: "Ipad",
    key: "ipad",
    keywords: ["tablet", "apple"],
    price: 800,
  },
  Iphone: {
    name: "Iphone",
    key: "iphone",
    keywords: ["apple", "phone"],
    price: 1200,
  },
  GalaxyTablet: {
    name: "GalaxyTablet",
    key: "galaxytablet",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "tablet", "samsung"],
    price: 800,
  },
  GalaxyPhone: {
    name: "GalaxyPhone",
    key: "galaxyphone",
    keywords: ["galaxy", "phone", "samsung"],
    price: 1000,
  },
  HTCPhone: {
    name: "HTCPhone",
    key: "htcphone",
    keywords: ["htc", "phone"],
    price: 650,
  },
  SonyPhone: {
    name: "SonyPhone",
    key: "sonyphone",
    keywords: ["sony", "phone"],
    price: 850,
  },
  WindowsPhone: {
    name: "WindowsPhone",
    key: "windowsphone",
    keywords: ["phone", "windows"],
    price: 800,
  },
};

const form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

function submitHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const searchTerm = form.box.value;
  const results = search(searchTerm);

  render(results);
}

function search(searchTerm) {
  return Object.keys(catalog)
    .filter((key) => catalog[key].keywords.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
    .map((key) => catalog[key]);
}

function render(results) {
  const root = document.querySelector("#root");
  const list = results.map(itemToLi).join("");

  root.innerHTML = `<ul>
    ${list}
  </ul>`;
}

function itemToLi(item) {
  return `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please insert the items</p>
  <input type="text" id="box" />
</form>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Update 0

In javascript there are several ways to create templates and then integrate them into your DOM. They are for example using the DOM API to create elements and nest them using methods like append, it is possible to use  to programmatically generate the content. There are also [literal templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that are usually quite simple to maintain. I comment on the above because you have at least these three ways of achieving the objective you are talking about. In the example use template literals, but now look at this example that uses

HTML

```
<ul id="root"></ul>

<template id="template">
  <li></li>
</template>
```

Javascript, use the same code just replace the render function logic and create the function createItemTemplate

```
function render(results) {
  const ul = document.querySelector("#root");

  results.forEach((entry) => {
    const item = createItemTemplate(entry);

    ul.appendChild(item);
  });
}

function createItemTemplate(item) {
  const template = document.querySelector("#template");
  const entry = template.content.cloneNode(true);

  entry.querySelector("li").textContent = item.name;

  return entry;
}
```

All of the above regarding how to dynamically create content and then associate it with your DOM

About the search

About the search, because catalog is an object, in my case I have required to obtain the keys of the catalog object, then filter these keys by searching catalog in the keys where the keywords property includes the search term and finally using map I obtain the object according to the key found

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Your example is simple, works, but given the vagueness of the question, it would have been more appropriate to provide direction, instead of the answer, given the question is most likely a practical exercise for the individual's education

Comment: I am agree Justin, when I answered I was about to have dinner, so I published my solution and thought then go back to comment and give a little guide

Answer (score 0):

There's about a million different typeahead/autocomplete/drop-down solutions on the internet that could solve this problem, but let's say you don't have access to those libs, or this is a practical exercise. In that case:

1. Add on [onChange](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) event listener to the input field, that when the value is changed, it performs a search
2. The onChange should include a [debouncer](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to prevent multiple requests in a short amount of time (250ms)
3. The debouncer calls a function that performs the search. The search should be a regex search against the `name` field in each object, eg. `name.test/(foo)/ig`
4. If results are found, call another function that builds the correctly structured UL/LI html
5. There should be a value that controls the display of the drop-down list, eg. `isOpen = true|false`
6. When the user clicks on a value, it should populate another global value, eg. `selectedValue` that references the entry in the `catalog` const, eg `selectedValue = Iphone`.
7. The value of the input field should be set to the catalog entry name value, eg. `Iphone`
8. The property `isOpen` should be set to false so that the list is no longer displayed, and the list should be deleted for better performance.

Once you've got that working, you can add additional functionality, such as enter/esc/up/down/left/right/tab handling, aria fields for visually impaired users, etc.

Or if you want to make your life easier, grab a React drop-down component.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed demo that should do what you're looking for (except we sell fish.)

```js
const
  // Gets catalog
  catalog = getCatalog(),

  // Gets an array of the properties in `catalog`
  catalogKeys = Object.keys(catalog),

  // Identifies HTML elements
  box = document.getElementById("box"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btn");

  // Calls `simulateFormSubmission` when button is clicked
  btn.addEventListener("click", simulateFormSubmission);  

// Defines `simulateFormSubmission` function
function simulateFormSubmission(){
  
  // Gets `searchKeyword` from the input element
  const searchKeyword = box.value.toLowerCase();

  // Ignores empty inputs
  if(searchKeyword.trim() === ""){ return; }
  
  // Defines the `finalResult` array
  let finalResult = [];
  
  // Clears the input element
  box.value = "";

  // Loops through property names in catalog
  for (let key of catalogKeys) {

    // Gets the object that is the value for this item
    const obj = catalog[key];

    // Adds current object to result if it matches
    if(obj.keywords.includes(searchKeyword)){
      finalResult.push(obj);
    }
  }
  if(!finalResult.length){
    finalResult.push("No fish for you!");
  }
  // Prints filtered catalog to console
  console.log(finalResult);
}




// Defines `getCatalog` function
function getCatalog(){
  return {
    RedFish: { name: "RedFish", keywords: ["red", "fish"] },
    BlueFish: { name: "BlueFish", keywords: ["blue", "fish"] }
  };
}
```

```css
#note{ color: grey; }
```

```html
<input id="box" />
<button id="btn">Search</button>
<p id="note">Note: Search for 'red', 'blue', or 'fish' for a positive result in the demo</p>
```